# requirejs optimizer just define module name only

Tags: javascript, requirejs, requirejs-optimizer

I want to use requirejs optimizer just to create/define the module name for my js file.

eg : if i have a file say test.js under modules/moduleA

```
modules
|
|
-----moduleA
     |
     -----test.js
```

i want requirejs optimizer to create just the module name for me based on path...eg below I want requirejs optimizer to create the module name modules/moduleA/test and put inside the define present in the test.js

Eg:
Before running requireJS optimizer

test.js content:

```
define( ["my/cart", "my/inventory"],
            function(cart, inventory) {
               ...
           }
        );
```

After running requirejs optimizer

test.js content

```
define("modules/moduleA/test",
            ["my/cart", "my/inventory"],
            function(cart, inventory) {
               ...
           }
        );
```

I Will take care of combining the related dependent files later by means of grunt ...but i want requirejs optimizer to visit each file and give me the module name based on path it presents.

Is this feasible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

James Burke the author of Requirejs provided an [answer to this](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/issues/835#issuecomment-125336982) via another forum.

We can easily do this via using transform from RequireJS:

> ```
> var requirejs = require('requirejs');
> requirejs.tools.useLib(function(require) {
>   require(['transform'], function (transform) {
>      //todo: generate a files array with the list of files to concatenate.
>
>       files.forEach(function(filePath) {
>         var fullPath = path.join(targetDir, filePath);
>         var contents = fs.readFileSync(fullPath, 'utf8');
>         var moduleId = /* todo, figure out what the moduleId is for the module */
>         var transformed = transform
>                           .toTransport('', moduleId, fullPath, contents);
>
>         //todo: concat the contents together
>       });
>     });
>   });
> });
> ```

Comment: Thanks @Louis for the edit. Its looks perfect now. Thanks for your help